# More than one autocomplete fields using javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have to use two auto-complete boxes but only first box works. The keywords are same for both fields e.g. one auto-complete field for location-1 and other for location-2.
Here is the working code for one auto-complete field box:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var data = ["Boston Celtics", "Chicago Bulls", "Miami Heat", "Orlando Magic", "Atlanta Hawks", "Philadelphia Sixers", "New York Knicks", "Indiana Pacers", "Charlotte Bobcats", "Milwaukee Bucks", "Detroit Pistons", "New Jersey Nets", "Toronto Raptors", "Washington Wizards", "Cleveland Cavaliers"];
            $("#seed_one").autocomplete({source:data});
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="seed_one" type="text" name="seed_one"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is the code of the not working one

Comment: And what is your question..???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For another autocomplete box you have create another input box and pass its `id` to `autocomplete` function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var data = ["Boston Celtics", "Chicago Bulls", "Miami Heat", "Orlando Magic", "Atlanta Hawks", "Philadelphia Sixers", "New York Knicks", "Indiana Pacers", "Charlotte Bobcats", "Milwaukee Bucks", "Detroit Pistons", "New Jersey Nets", "Toronto Raptors", "Washington Wizards", "Cleveland Cavaliers"];
        $("#seed_one").autocomplete({source:data});
        $("#seed_two").autocomplete({source:data});
    });
</script>
<body>
<input id="seed_one" type="text" name="seed_one"/>
<input id="seed_two" type="text" name="seed_two"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! I justed wanted that.